# What is wrong with this limit solution?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was solving this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\left(2x+3\right)!-\left(2x\right)!\right)}{\left(x^2\left(\left(2x+1\right)!-\left(2x\right)!\right)\right)}$$
After some simplifications i was left with: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(2x+3)(2x+2)(2x+1)-1}{2x^3}$$
I noticed that i had to simplify by $x^3$ so i mindlessly did:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3((\frac2{x^2}+\frac3{x^3})(\frac2{x^2}+\frac2{x^3})(\frac2{x^2}+\frac1{x^3})-\frac1{x^3})}{2x^3}=\frac02=0$$
After some reasoning though i solved the product arriving to: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(8x^3+24x^2+22x+5\right)}{2x^3}=\frac{x^3\left(8+\frac{24}{x}+\frac{22}{x^2}+\frac{5}{x^3}\right)}{2x^3}=\frac82=4$$
Which is the correct solution after some checking. What is wrong with the simplification before solving the product? i know that it might be an horrible error but i can't figure it out by myself.

Comment: You actually divided by $x^9$ on the left side of the numerator the first time around. You should only divide each of the three factors by $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that you factored out $x^3$ from ***each*** factor.
$$\begin{align*}
(2x+3)(2x+2)(2x+1)-1
\ne
x^3\left( \left( \frac2{x^2}+\frac3{x^3}\right) \left( \frac2{x^2}+\frac2{x^3}\right) \left( \frac2{x^2}+\frac1{x^3}\right) -\frac1{x^3}\right) 
\end{align*}$$
as
$$\begin{align*}
 \frac2{x^2}+\frac3{x^3} 
&= x^3 (2x+3) \\
\frac2{x^2}+\frac2{x^3}
&= x^3 (2x+2)\\
\frac2{x^2}+\frac1{x^3}
&= x^3 (2x+1)
\end{align*}$$
so in reality you would have $x^9$ out front, ignoring that this would be inconsistent with $1/x^3$ in lieu of $1/x^9$.

You should instead only factor out a factor of $x$ from each factor of $(2x+3)(2x+2)(2x+1)$, and a factor of $x^3$ from $-1$. This will salvage your approach.